# Probability distribution in GAN

Tags: machine-learning, probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, gan

Here is the general eauation of GAN. I have a problem regarding probability distribution of x and z.

$$\min_G \max_D V(D,G) = \mathbb{E}_{x\sim p_{data}(x)}[\log D(x)]+ \mathbb{E}_{z\sim p_{z}(z)}[\log (1- D(G(z)))]$$

Comparing above and below image we have -
$E_{x\sim p_{data}(x)}[\log(D(X))] = \frac1m\sum [\log(D(x_i)]$ which by definition of expectation should be $\sum (p_{data}(x_i)\cdot[\log(D(x_i)]$ where $(p_{data}(x_i))$ is the pdf value at $x_i$ which means $(p_{data}(x_i))$ is taken as $\frac1m$ for all $i$ is taken into account.

I am unable to understand why is this pdf value at $x_i$ is taken as $\frac1m$. Since we do not know the distribution of $p_{data}(x)$ so our best deal is to approximate it but why are we approximating it with $\frac1m$. Aren't distributions like gaussian distribution more appropriate for approximation. Similarly for $p_z(z)$.

[image]

Comment: I'll help you work out the answer for yourself intuitively. (1) Assume that the probability distribution is uniform - you should satisfy yourself that (1/m) makes sense. For simplicity if X was discrete like rolling a dice - then if you roll the dice 600 times, you'd expect to see roughly a 100 for each x (face). (2) if the dice was biased towards 1 , the X=1 would occur more frequently and the distribution should reflect that. If the dice is thrown m= 600 times you would get more hits for 1 and less hits for 2-6. At the end to get the probability you would have to divide everything by m=600.

Comment: Thanks Mellow its clear now.